# Where is Korean Trade Representative Contact Information displayed in the ios App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

In order for iOS apps developed by a company (as opposed to an individual) to be displayed on the Korean app store, Trade Representative Contact Information must be provided, including a name, e-mail, phone number, etc.

[iTunes Connect Properties - Trade Representative Contact Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW9)

I was wondering if this information is all publicly available on the Korean App Store.  Looking at, for instance, [Instagram on the Korean app store](https://itunes.apple.com/kr/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8&v0=WWW-NAUS-ITSTOP100-FREEAPPS&l=en&ign-mpt=uo%3D4#), clicking on "Developer Info" only shows:

```
Developer Info

Trade Name
Instagram, Inc.
```

Does this mean that only the company name is publicly displayed, but the rest of the contact info is stored internally for legal purposes?  Will clicking the "Display Trade Representative Contact Information on the Korean App Store" check box display the full information provided, or will it just show the company name like in the Instagram example?

I'm asking because my company wouldn't want to put, for instance, our CEO's main e-mail as a public trade representative e-mail (in that it could be subject to spam), and we might want to use different choices for a publicly available versus internally provided phone number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app is approved, and it looks like all trade rep information is displayed in a link on the Korean app store (after privacy policy, marketing URL, etc.; see circled link below)  Here's what it looks like:

[image: Korean trade rep information]